# Get cookie according to domain

Tags: cookies

I want to reset all previous cookie for particular domain.
Is there any way so I can get all the cookie for particular domain? Right now cookie I have cookies for google and my site. I want cookies only for my site.

Comment: Can We have more information please. Are you looking to remove cookies from your system, via an internet browser, or via Code like Asp, Php, .net, ... ?? The possibilities are endless, man !

Comment: I want to remove cookies via PHP. Is there any way to get all information about cookie? Right all I can get is name/value pair.

Comment: Do you want to remove the cookies for a domain from *your* computer, or from the computer of everyone who visits your **website**?

Comment: I want to remove the domain specific cookie from every visitor of our website. Like we have domain cookie for www.example.com & touch.example.com. I want to remove only cookie from touch.example.com.

Answer (score 0):

Expiring ( removing ) a cookie uses the same command as creating a cookie. The cookie value is left blank and the expiration time needs to be in the past.

To expire the cookie ‘mycookie’ use:

```
setcookie('mycookie','',1);
```

To retrieve cookie information, use:

```
// Print a cookie
echo $_COOKIE["mycookie"];

// View all cookies
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

You cannot get any more information than the information **you** store in the cookie. The cookie is not stored on the server, but on the *client* computer, that is the immediate reason why you can't get more information about the cookie.

I hope this is sufficient information to be an answer to you.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I got the point we can't all information about cookie :(.

Comment: I want domain name for the cookie?